# To Show Only Selected Div And Hide Rest All Other Divs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

There are four main divs i have one button and another container div in the main div. when i press the button the container div is visible and text of the button changes but all the main divs are visible my problem is i want to hide all other divs, the main div whose button is pressed should be visible along with the container div rest other main divs should be hidden . but i am not able to hide other main divs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.myButton').click(function(){
      if ( this.value == 'collapse' ) {
    // if it's open close it
    open = false;
    this.value = 'expand';
    $(this).next("div.container").hide("slow");
      }
      else {
    // if it's close open it
    open = true;
    this.value = 'collapse';
    $(this).next("div.container").show("slow");



  }
    });

  });
</script>



</head>
<body>
<?php
for($i=0;$i<=3;$i++)
{
echo"<div class='main' style='position:relative;border:1px solid #A5BEBE;background-color:         #E7EFEF;width:84%;  '> 
<b> sometext:-</b><a href='#'>$url</a><br>
<b>sometext :</b>$b<br>
<b>sometext :</b>$c<br>
<b>sometext :</b>$d<br>
<b>sometext :</b>$e<br>
<b>sometext :</b>$f<br>
<b>sometext :</b>$g</p>
<input type='button' value='expand' class='myButton'  target='".$i."'           style='position:absolute;left:85%;top:4%;background:#B20000;color:white;width:70px;height:20px;font-        size:15px;' >$i";

echo "<div  class='container'  style='display:none;background:white; '>

  <b> sometext:-</b><a href='#'>$url</a><br>
<b>sometext :</b>$b<br>
<b>sometext :</b>$c<br>
<b>sometext :</b>$d<br>
<b>sometext :</b>$e<br>
<b>sometext :</b>$f<br>
<b>sometext :</b>$g</p>
</div>";

echo "</div><br><br>";

}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

when we click a button two events are held 
1:- all other main divs and container divs are hidden leaving the one div whose button has been pressed
2:- the div whose button is pressed in that both the main div and container div are shown and the text of the button is changed to collapsed

when we click the button again the events held are 
1:- all the main divs are shown and container divs are hidden 
2:- text of the button is changed to expand 
out of the above mentioned events many have been achieved . Problem is we are not able to hide rest of the main div leaving the current main div whose button has been pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.myButton').click(function() {
    var $ct = $(this).next("div.container");
    if (this.value == 'collapse') {
      this.value = 'expand';
      $ct.hide("slow");
 $('.myButton').parent().show("slow");
    } else {
      this.value = 'collapse';
      $ct.show("slow");
 $('.myButton').not($(this)).parent().hide("hide");
    }



  });
});
```

This will hide all other divs

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.myButton').click(function() {
    var $ct = $(this).next("div.container");
    if (this.value == 'collapse') {
      this.value = 'expand';
      $ct.hide("slow");
 $('.myButton').parent().show("slow");
    } else {
      this.value = 'collapse';
      $ct.show("slow");
 $('.myButton').not($(this)).parent().hide("hide");
    }
   
  

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='main' style='position:relative;border:1px solid #A5BEBE;background-color:         #E7EFEF;width:84%;  '>
  <b> sometext:-</b><a href='#'>$url</a>
  <br>
  <b>sometext :</b>$b
  <br>
  <b>sometext :</b>$c
  <br>
  <b>sometext :</b>$d
  <br>
  <b>sometext :</b>$e
  <br>
  <b>sometext :</b>$f
  <br>
  <b>sometext :</b>$g
  <input type='button' value='expand' class='myButton' target='".$i."' style='position:absolute;left:85%;top:4%;background:#B20000;color:white;width:70px;height:20px;font-        size:15px;'>$i"; echo "
  <div class='container' style='display:none;background:white; '> <b> sometext:-</b><a href='#'>$url</a>

    <br>
    <b>sometext :</b>$b
    <br>
    <b>sometext :</b>$c
    <br>
    <b>sometext :</b>$d
    <br>
    <b>sometext :</b>$e
    <br>
    <b>sometext :</b>$f
    <br>
    <b>sometext :</b>$g</div>
</div>

<div class='main' style='position:relative;border:1px solid #A5BEBE;background-color:         #E7EFEF;width:84%;  '>
  <b> sometext:-</b><a href='#'>$url</a>
  <br>
  <b>sometext :</b>$b
  <br>
  <b>sometext :</b>$c
  <br>
  <b>sometext :</b>$d
  <br>
  <b>sometext :</b>$e
  <br>
  <b>sometext :</b>$f
  <br>
  <b>sometext :</b>$g
  <input type='button' value='expand' class='myButton' target='".$i."' style='position:absolute;left:85%;top:4%;background:#B20000;color:white;width:70px;height:20px;font-        size:15px;'>$i"; echo "
  <div class='container' style='display:none;background:white; '> <b> sometext:-</b><a href='#'>$url</a>

    <br>
    <b>sometext :</b>$b
    <br>
    <b>sometext :</b>$c
    <br>
    <b>sometext :</b>$d
    <br>
    <b>sometext :</b>$e
    <br>
    <b>sometext :</b>$f
    <br>
    <b>sometext :</b>$g</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can hide the rest of the containers like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $mains = $('.main');
  var $bts = $('.myButton').click(function() {
    var $ct = $(this).next("div.container"),
      $main = $(this).closest('.main');
    if (this.value == 'collapse') {
      this.value = 'expand';
      $ct.hide("slow");
      $mains.not($main).show()
    } else {
      this.value = 'collapse';
      $ct.show("slow");
      $mains.not($main).hide()
    }
    //hide other container elements
    $('div.container').not($ct).hide();
    $bts.not(this).val('expand');
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $mains = $('.main');
  var $bts = $('.myButton').click(function() {
    var $ct = $(this).next("div.container"),
      $main = $(this).closest('.main');
    if (this.value == 'collapse') {
      this.value = 'expand';
      $ct.hide("slow");
      $mains.not($main).show()
    } else {
      this.value = 'collapse';
      $ct.show("slow");
      $mains.not($main).hide()
    }
    //hide other container elements
    $('div.container').not($ct).hide();
    $bts.not(this).val('expand');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='main' style='position:relative;border:1px solid #A5BEBE;background-color:         #E7EFEF;width:84%;  '>
  <b> sometext:-</b><a href='#'>$url</a>
  <br>
  <b>sometext :</b>$b
  <br>
  <b>sometext :</b>$c
  <br>
  <b>sometext :</b>$d
  <br>
  <b>sometext :</b>$e
  <br>
  <b>sometext :</b>$f
  <br>
  <b>sometext :</b>$g
  <input type='button' value='expand' class='myButton' target='".$i."' style='position:absolute;left:85%;top:4%;background:#B20000;color:white;width:70px;height:20px;font-        size:15px;'>$i"; echo "
  <div class='container' style='display:none;background:white; '> <b> sometext:-</b><a href='#'>$url</a>

    <br>
    <b>sometext :</b>$b
    <br>
    <b>sometext :</b>$c
    <br>
    <b>sometext :</b>$d
    <br>
    <b>sometext :</b>$e
    <br>
    <b>sometext :</b>$f
    <br>
    <b>sometext :</b>$g</div>
</div>

<div class='main' style='position:relative;border:1px solid #A5BEBE;background-color:         #E7EFEF;width:84%;  '>
  <b> sometext:-</b><a href='#'>$url</a>
  <br>
  <b>sometext :</b>$b
  <br>
  <b>sometext :</b>$c
  <br>
  <b>sometext :</b>$d
  <br>
  <b>sometext :</b>$e
  <br>
  <b>sometext :</b>$f
  <br>
  <b>sometext :</b>$g
  <input type='button' value='expand' class='myButton' target='".$i."' style='position:absolute;left:85%;top:4%;background:#B20000;color:white;width:70px;height:20px;font-        size:15px;'>$i"; echo "
  <div class='container' style='display:none;background:white; '> <b> sometext:-</b><a href='#'>$url</a>

    <br>
    <b>sometext :</b>$b
    <br>
    <b>sometext :</b>$c
    <br>
    <b>sometext :</b>$d
    <br>
    <b>sometext :</b>$e
    <br>
    <b>sometext :</b>$f
    <br>
    <b>sometext :</b>$g</div>
</div>
```

Comment: all the main divs are shown. only the div whose button has pressed that div along with the container div should be shown rest all divs should be hidden.

Comment: thanks but the other main div is not hiding. it should also hide only the first div should be shown along with the container div